# Debuging unity game on Android Device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to see Debug Logs in real time from the phone?
I need to test things connected to google play services and it will be much easier to find bugs with console, not just by trying random fixing.

I tried to use adb from platform tools and [Debug Console](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DebugConsole)

Debug Console is not working for me. Same with adb (I can connect to the device, but it does not give me any logs. I'm not sure if I can use adb like that.

I thought that writting my "own" debug console can be a good idea, but it is time consuming.

Comment: Why is Debug Console not working?

Comment: It isn't showing anything when I write `DebugConsole.Log("test", "warning");` I have Debug Console script imported.

Comment: As far as I understand it should show me Yellow message "test" on device screen when the `DebugConsole.Log("test", "warning")` is called during runtime?